# Error -Installing user interface update for SDL Tridion 2011SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am installing user interface update for SDL Tridion 2011SP1.When I make  below entry in the 
cd_storage_conf.xml file

```
<Wrapper Name="SessionWrapper">
<Timeout>120000</Timeout>
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="db-session-staging" dialect="MSSQL"
Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
<Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60"
IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
<DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
<Property Name="serverName" Value="XYZ" />
<Property Name="portNumber" Value="123" />
<Property Name="databaseName" Value="XYZ" />
<Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
<Property Name="password" Value="xyz" />
</DataSource>
</Storage>
</Wrapper>
```

It is throwing below error.

> **NOTE:** - *Some time such error comes due to expiration of licence so I checked the licence file it is not expired anyway.*

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: Java.Lang.Throwable: Could not initialize class
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
>   Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded
>
> The most typical reasons for this problem are:
>
> - you forgot to configure a classpath
> - a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your   classpath
> - you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
> - a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from   your classpath
> - a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not   contain some new classes
>
> ============================================================
>
> com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.BinaryLinkHandler 
>   com.tridion.preview.web.BinaryContentFilter 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TaxonomyHandler 
>   com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataPublicationMappingFilter 
>   com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor  [Ljavax.servlet.http.Cookie; 
>   com.tridion.marketingsolution.profilesync.Handler 
>   com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataContextListener 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentPresentationHandler 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.IncrementKeyHandler 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TargetGroupHandler 
>   com.tridion.preview.web.PageContentFilter 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionHandler 
>   com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentLinkHandler 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionsHandler 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.DynamicComponentLinkHandler 
>   com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.PageLinkHandler  javax.servlet.http.Cookie 
>   com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
>   javax.servlet.ServletResponse  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.LinkBaseHandler
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  javax.servlet.ServletRequest 
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Please help me in this regard  as soon as possible.

Comment: The error indicates you are missing some jar files. Did you also copy `sqljdbc` jar file as well.

Comment: Did you check the rest of the jars are copied and you have the correct config ? When are you getting this error, as soon as you hit the preview URL (OR) when you try to edit using UI?

Comment: when i hit the HTTPUpload.aspx in my deployer website,it throws this error.

Comment: Hi Ram. Did you Set that tag under Storages/Wrappers? Did you turn on Tridion debug logging in your WebApp? Do you see any strange stack-trace in your logs? Did you also added the required jars: cd_preview_ambient.jar, cd_preview_web.jar, cd_session.jar, cd_preview_webservice.jar, footprint_cartridge.jar, se_ambientpreview.jar and hsqldb.jar? If you remove that configuration setting is your WebApp working?

Comment: Thanks Ram G and Sea_guil for your quick comments.May be I was missing any configuration steps so i reinstalled the UI again now this error has been resolved.

Comment: Hi Ram G and Sea_guil, previuosly i was getting the error when i was hitting the HTTPUpload.aspx in my deployer website. Now when i browse the published website it is throwing the same error again. Could you please give me a direction on this.

Answer (score 3):

As the message states, you're missing some jars somewhere. For a complete picture of what's needed for each CD role, you can read the [CD JAR file reference](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/reference_DB20ECA59C824CC3BBB4644187D2C57A) on LiveContent.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for nice and useful link. i was unable to find any missing  such jar file. so i reinstalled the UI again now this error has been resolved. May be I was missing any configuration step.

Comment: Hi Jeremy,previuosly i was getting this error when i was hitting the HTTPUpload.aspx in my deployer website. Now when i am browsing the published website it is throwing the same error on the page rather than showing on HttpUpload.aspx .Could you please give me a direction on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct JRE installed? If you are using a 64bit deployer website you will need to install the 64bit JRE as well...

Alternatively you might have accidentally left the AppPool of the deployer website on 32bits (which would essentially give you the same issue as you would now need a 32bit JRE).